# bash: expanding variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, expansion

I'm trying to add a function to my `.bashrc` to ease prepending `$PWD` to environment variables. I'd like the function to take one argument -- the name of the variable on which to prepend the working directory. I'm thinking something like this...

```
function prependTo{ export $1=$PWD:\$$1 }
```

Is what I'm looking to do possible in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `function` keyword, it is deprecated and non-POSIX.  Instead do this:

```
 prependTo(){ export $1=$PWD:${!1}; }
```

#### Explanation

From `man bash`

> If the first character of parameter is
>   an exclamation point, a level of
>   variable indirection is introduced. 
>   Bash  uses
>          the value of the variable formed from the rest of parameter as
>   the name of the variable; this
>   variable is then expanded
>          and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than
>   the value of parameter itself.  This 
>   is  known  as
>          indirect  expansion.